# Why is there a zero-width non-joiner and a zero-width space in my comment?

Tags: bug, comments

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628822/why-does-sidekiq-not-close-old-connections/28902361?noredirect=1#comment46090984_28902361)…

[image]

[image]

I did not  type that. Where does it come from?